# Is there an easy way to tell if a 2-surface is an Einstein manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

If one has a 2-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e. a 2-surface), is there an easy way to tell whether the Ricci curvature tensor for $\mathcal{M}$ is proportional to the (euclidean) induced metric on the manifold?

Or, more simply put, is there a way one can just reason whether or not the 2-surface is an Einstein manifold, as opposed to doing the explicit calculations?

Please forgive me if this is a well known (possibly repeated here) question.

Comment: What is the significance of the "2" in the phrase "2-surface"? What other kinds of surfaces are there?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I put it there just for clarity :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we work in an orthonormal frame, we have $R_{ij} = R_{1i1j} + R_{2i2j}$. Since we are in two dimensions, the first term is only non-zero when $i=j=2$ and likewise the second when $i=j=1$. Thus since $R_{1212} = R_{2121} = \kappa$ is the Gaussian curvature, we see that $R_{ij}$ is $\kappa$ when $i=j$ and zero otherwise - i.e. $$R_{ij} = \kappa g_{ij}.$$

Thus the Ricci curvature is always a *smooth* multiple of the metric, but only a constant one when the sectional/Gaussian/scalar curvature is constant. So the answer to your question is either "always" or "exactly in the constant-curvature case" depending on what kind of proportionality you mean by Einstein. In higher dimension these two kinds of proportionality are equivalent (Schur's Lemma), so the exact definition of Einstein can vary.

Assuming you're requiring $\kappa$ constant, this becomes the problem of recognizing surfaces of constant curvature, which is well studied in classical differential geometry - see e.g. Liebmann's theorem for the positive curvature case.